# Run multiple NPM commands vscode task

Tags: visual-studio-code, automation, task

I'm not very familiar with vscode tasks but I want to automate one tiny thing. Everytime I open my editor, I need to run 4 commands:

```
cd client
npm start

cd server
npm run dev
```

I'm just looking for a way to automate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ANSWER:

> ###### There is currently no support for running a task when VS-Code is opened, however; VSCode added support, roughly 2 years ago, for running a task when a directory is opened.

---

#### EXAMPLE #1:

> ###### This is what the configuration property looks like:

```
// THIS EXAMPLE WAS ORIGINALLY AUTHORED @ 
// VSCode appendix (TASKS) - "https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix" 


 // NOTE: This is written in typescript, and hasn't been compiled (which is probably obvious to most). See below for a real world example:

interface RunOptions {

/** ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Controls how variables are evaluated when a task is executed through
 * the Rerun Last Task command.
 * The default is `true`, meaning that variables will be re-evaluated when
 * a task is rerun. When set to `false`, the resolved variable values from
 * the previous run of the task will be used.  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

  reevaluateOnRerun?: boolean;



/** ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * SPECIFIES WHEN A TASK WILL RUN:
 *
 * VALID VALUES ARE:
 *    "default": The task will only be run when executed through the Run Task command.
 *    "folderOpen": The task will be run when the containing folder is opened.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

  runOn?: string;
}
    }
```

---

#### EXAMPLE #2:

> ###### **`runOptions` is added as a base property to the task, a real life example looks like this:**

```
// THIS EXAMPLE WAS ORIGINALLY AUTHORED @ 
// VSCode's v(1.30) Release Notes - "https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks"

// FILENAME: .../.vscode/tasks.json

{
  "type": "npm",
  "script": "strict-null-check-watch",
  "label": "TS - Strict Null Checks",
  "isBackground": true,
  "problemMatcher": {
    "base": "$tsc-watch",
    "owner": "typescript-strict-null",
    "applyTo": "allDocuments"
  },
  "runOptions": {
    "runOn": "folderOpen"
  }
}
```

---

###### For more information, visit the **Official V.S. Code** sources below

> ---
>
> ##### Sources:
>
> ###### * Example 1)   [VSCode appendix (TASKS)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks-appendix)
>
> ###### * Example 2)   [VSCode's v(1.30) Release Notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks)
>
> ---

---

###### EDIT 2021 JUNE 17th @ 7:35pm UTC

###### Note: I can explain how to run four commands in a sequence, but I don't know if it will change your situation all that much. Read below, and Ill explain how to run the commands, then I will explain why that is not likely going to work.

---

### How to Run 4 Commands in a Sequence:

So, I know this works in the **Ubuntu Shell**, and I would expect that it executes fine in Powershell. As I stated earlier, I use Linux 100%, and nothing else.   If Powershell is a true shell, as its name suggest, then it will work...

###### Any-who, give this a go:

In the command line type each command with a **SEMI-COLON** (**`;`**) appended to the end each-one. You don't have to append a semi-colon to the last command. What the semi-colon does, is it tells the shell where the end of a command is at. When the shell reads the text after the semi-colon, it now knows that it is reading a new command, and it will continue to interpret that new command as a single separate command that ends at the next semi colon. The process continues recursively... you can enter 100 commands in one line this way.

###### EXAMPLE: 4 Commands in Sequence

```
    ~/$ cd client; npm start; cd server; npm run dev
```

---

#### I may have bad news for you

You are trying to start a server, and a client in one go. I am guessing that they wont be able to both be able to use the same terminal to start, and run, their instances. If the terminal runs a program that doesn't end, like a server, the terminal wont be able to start another program until the server is done running, therefore you will need to open another terminal to run your client in.

Comment: Ok fine. Is there a way to either run a task(by opening command palette and selecting said task) manually? Even that is fine.

Comment: The term command palette is yucky to me, but that's okay. Lets me know your using windows. I am not totally sure what you mean by _"said task"_ but you most certainly can run a task as a command from the VSCode Terminal. Useally when it is ran like this, you attach it to a keybinding.

Comment: You know you probably could setup a file-watcher, and a Gulp task if you wanted, but you would have to run it as a program in the background for windows. You wouldn't be able to define it in a VSCode "tasks.json" file, and accomplish what you are asking. Often, developers like my self, prefer Linux for reason like this. Creating a program and running it in Linux, that uses a simple file-watcher task, is a simple thing to set up when using Mint/Ubuntu, however, windows makes doing stuff like that harder that it needs to be.

Comment: By command palette I meant pressing Command + Shift + P.... I just want to squeeze those 4 commands into one.

Comment: @Akash Alrighty Akash, I updated my answer in an attempt to try and help you figure this out. I have a new suggestion for you that is appended to the bottom of my old answer.  Read it, try it, then let me know what you think.

Comment: No problem @Akash anytime. You can email me @ W3Dojo@Gmail.com or contact me on github  https://GitHub.com/W3Dojo if you ever have any more questions.